# Images in Ionic App

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, imagesloaded

I'm wondering what would be the best method to display images within an app?

Is it best to pull the URL when doing a get request or is it faster to use base64 and decode ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Uses a base 64 image, Don't allow the images to slow down rendering of pages. Use defer loading of images.

The HTML:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" data-src="your-image-here">
```

The JavaScript:

```
<script>
function init() {
var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i<imgDefer.length; i++) {
if(imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
} } }
window.onload = init;
</script>
```

> **Usage:**
>
> For most pages you can simply put the script right before the
>   end body tag in your html. As far as the images go you want to copy
>   the code above (labeled "the html") and replace "your-image-here" with
>   your actual image path.

This blog will help you.
https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-images.html